# How to list all the files that are checked in under perforce job?

Tags: perforce, p4v

I got a perforce job and would like to list all the files that are checked in against the job for code review. I want full file path for those files. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p4 -Ztag -F@=%Change% fixes -j JOBNAME | p4 -x - files
```